# How to switch to a low priviliged mode in Riscv?

Tags: riscv

I read the specs, but I still don't understand how to achieve that ?
So can someone show me how can you switch to a low privileged mode in riscv in baremetal applications ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in machine mode:
You could clear the MPP bits of the mstatus CSR and execute a mret instruction. Then you will end up at the address stored in mepc and you will be in user mode.